# GLUT rotating camera using key press not working

Tags: c, glut, freeglut

I'm trying to move the camera around the object I loaded, but for some reason the key presses are not working.

I took the relevant code from a previous project I was working on, which worked.

Can someone point me in the the right direction of why they are not working?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#ifdef __APPLE__
  #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
  #include <OpenGL/glu.h>
  #include <GLUT/glut.h>
#elif __linux__
  #include <GL/glut.h>
#endif


float camera_position_x = 0.0, camera_position_y = 0.1, camera_position_z = 0.2;
float line_of_sight_x = 0.0, line_of_sight_y = 0.2, line_of_sight_z = 0.0;
GLuint objObject;
char ch='1';


void InitGL (int width, int height)     // We call this right after our OpenGL window is created.
{
  glClearColor (255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f); // This will clear the background color to white
  glClearDepth (1.0);           // Enables clearing of the depth buffer
  glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);        // The type of depth test to do
  glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);     // Enables depth testing
  glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);     // Enables smooth color shading
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity ();            // Reset the projection matrix
  gluPerspective (45.0f, (GLfloat) width / (GLfloat) height, 0.1f, 100.0f); // Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
  glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void loadObj(char *fname)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int read;
    GLfloat x, y, z;
    char ch;
    objObject=glGenLists(1);
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("can't open file %s\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }
    glPointSize(2.0);
    glNewList(objObject, GL_COMPILE);
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        while(!(feof(fp)))
        {
            read=fscanf(fp,"%c %f %f %f",&ch,&x,&y,&z);
            if(read==4&&ch=='v')
            {
                glVertex3f(x,y,z);
            }
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();
    fclose(fp);
}

void ReSizeGLScene (int width, int height)
{
    if (height == 0)                  // Prevent A Divide By Zero If The Window Is Too Small
      {
        height = 1;
      }
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective (90, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 200.0);
    //gluLookAt(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gluLookAt(camera_position_x, camera_position_y, camera_position_z,
                line_of_sight_x, line_of_sight_y,  line_of_sight_z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void drawobjObject()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,-40.00,-105);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.23,0.27);
    glScalef(600,600,600);
    glCallList(objObject);
    glPopMatrix();

}
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    drawobjObject();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

    switch(key)
    {
        case 'a':
            line_of_sight_y += 3.0f;
            camera_position_y += 3.0f;
            break;
        case 'z':
            line_of_sight_y -= 3.0f;
            camera_position_y -= 3.0f;
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}

void arrowkey(int key, int x, int y) {


    switch(key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_UP :

                line_of_sight_z += 3.0f;
                camera_position_z += 3.0f;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN :

                line_of_sight_z -= 3.0f;
                camera_position_z -= 3.0f;
                break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT :

                    line_of_sight_x += 3.0f;
                    camera_position_x += 3.0f;
                break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:

                    line_of_sight_x -= 3.0f;
                    camera_position_x -= 3.0f;
                break;
    }
}
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,450);
    glutInitWindowPosition(20,20);
    glutCreateWindow("ObjLoader");
    glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(arrowkey);
    loadObj("bunny.obj");
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you encountered those squiggly little things everybody else is using when writing text? I am thinking, for example, of: ".,;?". Please edit your question for readability, in order to give the impression that you value their input and the time they spend on it, even if it means that you have to spend some care and effort yourself.

Comment: did you try switching these two:
`    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);`
`    glutSpecialFunc(arrowkey);`
I mean use `glutKeyboardFunc(arrowkey);`

Comment: No as I edited comment just switch arrowkey and keyboard parameters.

Comment: Please describe/expalin "not working". You are pressing one of those buttons, then you are resizing the window (in order to make the geometry changes inside `ReSizeGLScene()` effective, which otherwise seem not to have an influence) and then you observe that nothing has changed?

Comment: I love unfortunate acronyms, such as [GLUT](https://ling.pl/slownik/polsko-angielski/glut)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the desired change of geometry only happens when `ReSizeGLScene()` is called; because the keyboard callbacks only change variables. And the variables in turn only are accessed inside `ReSizeGLScene()`.
 So the change might only be observable when pressing one of the buttons and then e.g. stretch the window a little.

I expect that a solution would be to call `ReSizeGLScene()` from both keyboard callbacks, using previously stored values for height and width.
But you probably want to optimise that and do the `gluLookAt()` separately, to be triggered from the keyboard-callbacks and from the resizer.